# How can I implement these bash commands in Google Colab

Tags: bash, pytorch, google-colaboratory, transformer-model

I'm a beginner who is working on Neural Machine Translation, the transformer model. I want to implement [fairseq Scaling Neural Machine Translation](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/scaling_nmt) using Google Colab. I guess the commands shown in the README file is written in bash. I know that bash commands can be run in Google Colab by prefixing the command with `!`. Following commands are from the Github repository mentioned above.

```
TEXT=wmt16_en_de_bpe32k
mkdir -p $TEXT
tar -xzvf wmt16_en_de.tar.gz -C $TEXT
```

These commands throw errors when I add the `!` as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual bash commands marked by `!` are executed in a sub-shell, so variables aren't preserved between lines. If you want to execute a multi-line bash script, use the `%%bash` cell magic:

```
%%bash
TEXT=wmt16_en_de_bpe32k
mkdir -p $TEXT
tar -xzvf wmt16_en_de.tar.gz -C $TEXT
```